# Laravel parameter grouping (orWhere) not working as expected

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

My data model is as follows: one request has zero or more offers. Requests have a status: accepted, cancelled, pending. Offers have a host_id.

What I'd like to query is: all requests in pending, OR all requests in accepted/cancelled state that have a host id equal to the one given.

Following this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping here is my code:

```
$offers = Request::whereIn('request_status', array($clientOfferPending))
                 ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($hostId, $clientOfferAccepted, $clientOfferCancelled) {
                     $query->whereIn('request_status', array($clientOfferAccepted, $clientOfferCancelled))
                           ->whereHas('host_offers', function ($query) use ($hostId) {
                                $query->where('host_id', $hostId);
                           });
                 });
```

Unfortunately this returns also requests in accepted state not owned by the host _id given.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Log `$offers->toSql()` to see what the raw query looks like, that should help narrow it down.

Comment: Here is the result: select * from "requests" where "request_status" in (?) or ("request_status" in (?, ?) and exists (select * from "offers" where "requests"."id" = "offers"."request_id" and "host_id" = ?)) and exists (select * from "offers" where "requests"."id" = "offers"."request_id" and "hide" = ?) or not exists (select * from "offers" where "requests"."id" = "offers"."request_id")

Comment: Are you sure the variables $clientOfferPending, $clientOfferAccepted and $clientOfferCancelled contain the values you think they contain? Can you replace those variables with its scalar values in the query and check if the it works that way?

Comment: You were right! The values weren't populated correctly! I've substituted the variables with integers (representing the IDs of the request statuses) and everything works as expected!